# How should I orginize stocks history data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My goal is to store the whole history of the stocks in the global in database.

the history is daily and each row of each stock should contain the date, open, close, high, low and volume.

I first though to create a table that will be something like:

id, stock symbol, date, open, close, low, high, volume

but it will be a table with millions of rows what I think I need to prevent.

another solution I thought is to create a table for each rows, but with this solution I will get a database with thousands of tables, what I think is wrong to.

Comment: Your project seems normal. Millions of rows is nothing. If you really want to save space and query time, you could create a summary table with just the months or years (Ex.: Everything older than 1 year would be aggregated to the summary table and removed from the original table). But you would lose the daily detail that could be helpful.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to optimize a database that is too slow... in your mind. What do you think about trying to make it work first? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go with your first idea - a single table with millions of rows. Although it sounds like a lot, any database software worth its salt should be able to cope with this, if used correctly. The single table approach also has the benefit of simplicity, and makes it easy to query all of your data at once.

Conversely, if you had many tables, this would make querying all your data much more complicated, and would also perhaps require you to make ongoing schema changes as your data set broadens, which probably isn't desirable.