# Structuring database for financial data

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms

I have a lot of stocks price data saved in CSV files that I've been collecting for a while and intend to keep collecting, but now into a DB instead of CSVs.
There are 73 files (a file for each asset), each with around 2 million rows. The data is formatted the same way in all of them:

```
date, timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume
```

I want to create a individual table for each of the CSV files because:

- For the uses I have in mind, I wont need more than one asset at once.
- I know 140 million lines isn't a heavy load for a RDBMS, but I think it would have a better perfomance searching a table of 2M records instead of 140M.
- Separating by asset I can have a column with Unique constraints (like date or timestamp) and prevent records being duplicated.

**Are any of those points a wrong assumption or bad practice? Is there a compelling reason to save them all in a single table?**

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714068/how-should-i-orginize-stocks-history-data), although a similar problem don't think the answer applies to my case.

In case it wasn't clear, I don't have much experience with DBs, so guidance and educational answers are heavily appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store them in a single table just because I wouldn't have to maintain 73 tables.
If you update your data on a daily or weekly or even monthly basis you would have to insert into 73 tables from 73 csv files, or maintain an automated script for that purpose which I think is a bit too much for this.

- For the uses I have in mind, I wont need more than one asset at once. -> I don't understand this.
- Separating by asset I can have a column with Unique constraints (like date or timestamp) and prevent records being duplicated. -> If you store them in a single table you could add a column asset_id, which would identify for which asset and date, timestamp is the data for.
- I know 140 million lines isn't a heavy load for a RDBMS, but I think it would have a better perfomance searching a table of 2M records instead of 140M. -> You could partition your table on date and asset_id, but this is a much broader discussion, with the details you've given I would do this.

Comment: I don't understand how your suggestion of a `asset_id` column would help prevent duplicates. Do you mean like concatenating the asset + date and have a Unique constrain on the column or something else?

Comment: assed_id would be just to know for which asset is the data. 
To prevent duplicates before every insert i suggest this: 
find max date grouped by asset_id from the table
insert new data for every asset that has a csv file for a date that is after it's max date in the table. 
I'm suggesting this because if you don't use constraints in your table the insert will be faster. asset_id, date is most certainly not a unique key in this table, so instead of doing a unique constraint on the whole row i suggest this prevention of duplicate insertion.